# How to extract the common logic including return statement in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, refactoring

Here is my code:

```
function function1() {
    var ids = GetIds(); // predefined function
    if (ids.length === 0) {
        alert("Please select at least one item to procees.");
        return;
    }

    ...
}

function function2() {
    var ids = GetIds(); // predefined function
    if (ids.length === 0) {
        alert("Please select at least one item to procees.");
        return;
    }

    ...
}

function function3() {
    var ids = GetIds(); // predefined function
    if (ids.length === 0) {
        alert("Please select at least one item to procees.");
        return;
    }

    ...
}
```

How to extract the common part out? How to re-factor the code? The return statement is very hard to deal with. Is there any pattern relating to re-factor this code?

Thanks in advance!

```
    if (ids.length === 0) {
        alert("Please select at least one item to procees.");
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Make a function containing the common part, and call the function in place of the common part.  You can't extract the "return" statement, because moving it somewhere else would mean it doesn't do its job where it is located.

Comment: The common part? But all three functions have the exact same function body. Why do you have three functions with the same body? .... A WHILE LATER: Ah the dots, I see... `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The only thing you can do is moving the `alert()` into `GetIds()`. However, the function name would be a bit confusing in this case.

```
var ids = GetIds();
if(!ids) return;
```

Or you could change it like this:

```
GetIds(function(ids) {

});
```

Your `GetIds` function would then look e.g. like this:

```
function GetIds(callback) {
    var ids = ....;
    if(!ids) alert('...');
    else callback(ids);
}
```

Comment: But the return statement in the callback function still return the workflow to the main function.

Comment: Yes, with that version you are supposed to put all your code after the original `return` in the callback function. It is impossible to make the calling function return from another function without an `if(whatever) return;` in the calling function.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good fit for the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

```
function decorateGetId(f) {
  return function () {
    var ids = GetIds();
    if (ids.length === 0) {
      alert("Please select at least one item to process.");
      return;
    } else {
      return f(ids);
    }
  };
}
```

then either

```
function function1(ids) {
  // ...
}
function1 = decorateGetId(function1);
```

or my preference, because the function statement does weird things with hoisting.

```
var function2 = decorateGetId(function (ids) {
  // function 2 body ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
function checkId(ids) {
    if (ids.length === 0) {
        alert("Please select at least one item to procees.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function function1() {
    var ids = GetIds();
    if (!checkId(ids)) return;

    // More code here
}
```

Comment: Why don't you move GetIds into checkIds?